# Retrieving data from my Web Service in Java / Android. android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, http, networking

The following code is used to fetch data from my web service and store it on my app:

```
//GET APP INFORMATION
public static String getAppInformation() {

    String data = "";
    //test the get method data retrieval using the HttpRequest Class

    try {
        data = makeHttpRequest("http://www.mywebsite.com/abc.php?action=abc.get");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

How do I STOP getting the "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" exception and also return the data variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your getAppInformation from thread, not from oncreate()

```
class CallDemo extends Thread
{
  public void run()
  {
        getAppInformation()
  }
}
```

and from oncreate()

```
 new CallDemo().start();
```

By using asynctask

```
class DemoClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String result=getAppInformation();

        return result;
    }

}
```

and oncreate code

```
try
    {
        DemoClass d=new DemoClass();
        d.execute("");
        String data=d.get();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: So how do I return what I get from getAppInformation() ?

Comment: for that purpose you can use asynctask class

Comment: i'm just not getting it

Comment: Right, got it working thanks to you Ravi :D Thanks a lot for your feedback & patience :)